# Docker image to be reread by kubernetes google cloud

Tags: image, docker, kubernetes, cloud, gcloud

as I am green to that subject, could you pls. help.

I deploy docker image to gcloud kubernetes.

What to do to make the cluster reread the docker image when a new one would appear?

My code is:

```
sudo docker build -t gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/sf:$ENV .
sudo docker push gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/sf:$ENV
sudo gcloud container clusters create sf:$ENV --num-nodes=3
sudo kubectl run sfmill-web$ENV --image=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/sf:$ENV --port 8088
sudo kubectl expose deployment sfmill-web$ENV --type=LoadBalancer --port 8088 --target-port 8088
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl set image deployment/sfmill-web$ENV sf=sf:$ENV
```

I encourage you to explore use Kubernetes configuration files to define resources.

You can explore the YAML for your deployment with:

```
kubectl get deployment/sfmill-web$ENV --output=yaml > ${PWD}/sfmill-web$ENV.yaml
```

You could then tweak the value of the `image` property and then reapply this to your cluster using:

```
kubectl apply --filename=${PWD}/sfmill-web$ENV.yaml
```

The main benefit to the configuration file approach is that you're effectively creating code to manage your infrastructure and, each time you change your code, you could check it into source control thereby knowing what you did at each stage.

Using `kubectl` is great *but* it makes it more challenging to recreate the cluster from scratch.... Which `kubectl` command did I perform next? Yes, you could (bash) script all your `kubectl` commands too which would help but configuration files remain the ideal solution.

HTH